# Method with numpy gives different result when called with array

Tags: python, numpy

I created a cosine similarity method, which gives the correct results when called with indivdual vectors, but when I supply a list of vectors I suddenly get different results. Isn't numpy supposed to calculate the formula for every element in the list? Is my understanding wrong?

Cosine similarity:

```
def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
  return np.inner(vec1, vec2) / (np.linalg.norm(vec1) * np.linalg.norm(vec2))
```

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
print(cosine_similarity(a, a), cosine_similarity(a, b), cosine_similarity(a, [a, b]))
```

With the result:

```
1.0 0.9746318461970762 [0.39223227 0.8965309 ]
```

The first two values are correct, the array of values should be the same, but isn't.
Is this just not possible or do I have to change something?

Comment: My first guess is, that the `np.linalg.norm(vec2)` needs to be called with the `axis` argument. When passing `[a,b]` into the norm function without `axis=-1` it computes the norm of a 2x3 matrix instead of the norm of each vector

Comment: Just confirmed that using `np.linalg.norm(vec2, axis=-1)` works as you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is actually correct. Many functions in numpy allow the keyword argument `axis` to be specified on call. `np.linalg.norm` for example computes the norm along the specified axis. In your case, if it is not specified, `norm` calulates the norm of the 2x3 matrix `[a, b]` instead calculating the norm per row.
To fix the code just do the following:

```py
def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
  return np.inner(vec1, vec2) / (np.linalg.norm(vec1) * np.linalg.norm(vec2, axis=-1))
```

Comment: The alternative is to transpose `vec2`